# jQuery Booklet plugin with iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.
I'm trying to make a book for the iPad, using the jQuery Booklet plugin and jQuery UI for iPad. However, on the iPad, I can't turn the pages. Any solutions?
Demo [here](http://www.actuary88.com/ipadapp1)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the .click() event, that's not raised, because iPad and iPhone only raise touch events.

To circumvent that, you have to add eventListeners.

Read up on http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript for reference

Comment: Well, I'm using jQuery UI for iPad (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/), which makes jQuery UI draggable work with touch events. In [this simple example](http://actuary88.com/ipadapp1/drag.html), drag works on the iPad. I have a feeling it's something with the booklet plugin, but I haven't been able to pinpoint it yet.

Comment: In the working example, you're including the script TouchSwipe and jquery.ui.touch.js, which does exactly what i was talking about in my answer, add EventListeners for touches. This is not happening in your other example, as there's no script that is doing that

Comment: The jquery.ui.ipad.altfix script is almost the same as the jquery.ui.touch script. The only difference is for the altfix script you must call it manually, while for the ui.touch script it does it automatically. I changed them out anyway and it still doesn't work right.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out the problem now. In a desktop browser, the preview of the next page appears when you hover near the edge. On mousedown, you can start dragging to turn the page. On an iPad, the jquery UI Touch script simulates a mouseover event on touchstart because there's no true "mouseover" on iPads. Now i just need to work out a solution. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Hi Abraham, I ran into the same problem, did you ever found a solution?